# Mean JS stack, create a factory that handles two different paths

Tags: javascript, angularjs, crud, meanjs, factories

I am using the MEAN JS framework and pretty much everything that came with it. 
However, I am trying to add a custom query when a user goes to a specific path (url). 
This is the code that came with MEAN JS: (in modules/articles/client/services)

```
'use strict';

//Articles service used for communicating with the articles REST endpoints
angular.module('articles').factory('Articles', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/articles/:articleId', {
      articleId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

And this takes care of all the functions defined in the controller, which are: `create, update, find, findOne, remove`. Now I am trying to add another function, 
`$scope.findByCategory = function (category) {...}` in the controller. 
But in order for it to communicate with the server, I need to add the path to the services.

**How do I do that? How do I edit my service (or factory) so it takes care for all the functions that I define in my controller. ( I have already set up the routes in the server side.)
Said in other words, I want to combine the above code and the below code into one piece in my client service.** Note: the only thing changing is the path.

```
//Articles service used for communicating with the articles REST endpoints
angular.module('articles').factory('Articles', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/articles/category', {
      articleId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way to do it, you could do another factory called `Category` or you can use the same returning an object like this:

```
angular.module('articles').factory('Articles', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return {
            articles: $resource('api/articles/:articleId', {
                articleId: '@_id'
            }, {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            }),
            categories: $resource('api/articles/:articleId/category', {
                articleId: '@_id'
            }, {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            })
        };
    };
]);
```

You will call them from a controller with for example `Articles.articles.get()` and `Articles.categories.get()`

And probably you want to change the category route to `api/articles/:articleId/category` so it get categories for the `articleId`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I will consider your suggestions. I will eventually have another schema for Tags, so maybe it would make sense to have two controllers and two factories.